# Display char count, 'Inside' HTML Textarea element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to nest a char-count value inside a HTML text area, just like the image below. I'm still a Js rookie so any advice is more than welcome. I have done some digging and haven't really come across anything that  could really help me.

As I don't have access to the CSS or HTML files directly I have to target these elements through Js. My question is can something like the image below, be done completely in Js? If so where do I start?

The elements  ID' is `= 'desinp'`
I'll include my current [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9s6zr718/) of what I have at this point in time.

[image: Char Count Example.]

Comment: No jQuery? No CSS? Tough dude. But possible.

Comment: Sadly no, all I can work with is Js. :( // But do tell. I'm eager to learn. :)

Answer (score 8):

To do this completely in JavaScript you have to change the HTML dynamically, and insert the proper elements in the correct places, and then add an event handler etc.

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
var text    = document.getElementById("desinp");
var c_wrap  = document.createElement('div');
var count   = document.createElement('span');

wrapper.style.position = 'relative';
c_wrap.style.position = 'absolute';
c_wrap.style.bottom = '8px';
c_wrap.style.color = '#ccc';
c_wrap.innerHTML = 'Char :';

text.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);
wrapper.appendChild(text);

c_wrap.appendChild(count);
wrapper.appendChild(c_wrap);

text.style.color = "#ccc";
text.style.resize = "none";
text.style.height = "auto";
text.rows = "3";

function _set() {
 c_wrap.style.left = (text.clientWidth - c_wrap.clientWidth - 12) + 'px';
 count.innerHTML = this.value.length || 0;
}

text.addEventListener('input', _set);
_set.call(text);
```

```html
<!-- textarea. -->
<textarea style="width: 364px; height: 149px;" class="required" id="desinp" name="desinp" maxlength="150"></textarea>
```

Comment: Very intuitive, it's much closer than I could have achieved on my own. However, I'm still having difficulties with this. because of the new elements being generated.

Comment: @Null - I guess you have to improve and tweak it yourself to fit exactly, but that's at least how you target elements, append elements, add event handlers etc.

Comment: NICE!! I was playing around with appending the character count to the text area and then moving it with position:relative etc, but this is much nicer!

Comment: I will do, thanks for the assistance. I'll post the finished resolution when I figure it all out.

Answer (score 5):

I have added a snippet of Javascript which would count the remaining characters, you can add up the characters if you want to show the total characters typed, you can design the element as per your need. The rest of code is from your fiddle.

```js
// Char limit.
function maxLength(el) {
  if (!('maxLength' in el)) {
    var max = el.attributes.maxLength.value;
    el.onkeypress = function() {
      if (this.value.length >= max) return false;
    };
  }
}

maxLength(document.getElementById("desinp"));

document.getElementById('desinp').onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Characters left: " + (150 - this.value.length);
};

// Element style over-ride.
document.getElementById("desinp").style.color = "#ccc";
document.getElementById("desinp").style.resize = "none";
document.getElementById("desinp").style.height = "auto";
document.getElementById("desinp").rows = "3";
```

```html
<!-- textarea. -->
<textarea style="width: 364px; height: 149px;" class="required" id="desinp" name="desinp" maxlength="150" ></textarea>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Comment: You can set the style with the script too so it will be looks "inside" text `textarea`.

Comment: @MoshFeu yes but let the op owner do something, atleast the cSS ;)

Comment: This is the issue, any newely rendered HTML element by Js is not being displayed on the page. I have to obey or overide, the original CSS Styling. I would rather obey the original styling because If I override it; it may mess with the page elsewhere.